# How to make a button change colors by binding in a class

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, colors, mouseevent

I tried to use bind to bind the mouse clicks to change colors based on the foreground and background of the buttons

```
from tkinter import *


class Clicks():
    def __init__(self, master):
        frame=Frame(master)
        frame.pack()

        #trying to bind the mouse clicks to change the color of the button

        self.button1= Button(frame, text="Click Me!", fg='red', bg='black')

        self.button1.bind("<Button-1>", fg='black')
        self.button1.bind("<Button-3>", bg='red')
        self.button1.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = W)


root = Tk()
b = Clicks(root)
root.mainloop()
```

TypeError: bind() got an unexpected keyword argument 'fg'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the snippet. You can use 2 approaches here.

First you can `bind` using `lambda` function

```
from tkinter import *
class Clicks():
    def __init__(self, master):
        frame=Frame(master)
        frame.pack()
        self.button1= Button(frame, text="Click Me!", fg='red', bg='black')
        self.button1.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event, b=self.button1: b.configure(bg="green",fg="blue"))
        self.button1.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = W)
root = Tk()
b = Clicks(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Second you can do via passing `command` to access function

```
from tkinter import *
class Clicks():
    def __init__(self, master):
        frame=Frame(master)
        frame.pack()
        self.button1= Button(frame, text="Click Me!",command=self.color, fg='red', bg='black')
        self.button1.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = W)
    def color(self):
        self.button1.configure(bg = "green",fg="blue")
root = Tk()
b = Clicks(root)
root.mainloop()
```